# Did B. R. Ambedkar say it is shameful for women to enter politics?

Tags: quotes, india

[B. R. Ambedkar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B._R._Ambedkar) was an Indian politician in the 1940s-50s who helped write the Indian constitution.

The Indian government hosts a web-page of his [writings and speeches](https://www.mea.gov.in/books-writings-of-ambedkar.htm). Vol. 40, Page No. 467 is in Hindi:

> फिलहाल काँग्रेस की राजनीति में महिलाओं की संख्या बढ़ाई जा रही है।
> महिलाओं की इस काँग्रेसी राजनीति के बारे में कुछ समझ नहीं आ रहा।
> **स्वधर्म छोड़ कर महिलाएं राजनीति करते हुए घूमें इसके जैसी शर्म की बात
> कोई और नहीं।** महाराष्ट्र की महिलाओं द्वारा अब केवल 'कासोटा'
> (महाराष्ट्री ढंग से साड़ी पहनते हुए नौ गज की साड़ी का पीछे की ओर खोंसा
> गया सिरा। इसके खुलने से एक तरह से साड़ी खुल जाती है। व्यंजनार्थ है -
> लाज-शरम या मर्यादा का त्याग करना) खोलना ही बाकी रह गया है। **काँग्रेस
> द्वारा 222 महिलाओं को लोकसभा में लेने का निर्णय लिया गया है। महिलाएं
> विधानसभा में जाएंगी तो पुरुष क्या करेंगे?** दिन भर लोकसभा में रहने के
> बाद जब फाइलें बगल में दबाए महिलाएं घर लौटेंगीं तब क्या उनके पति टेबिल
> पर भोजन रखेंगे? ये महिलाएं दिन भर पार्लियामेंट-एसेंब्ली में जाएंगी और
> शाम को घर लौटने के बाद पति से पूछेंगी,
> अजी सुनते हो, मैं पार्लियामेंट से आ गई हूं। घर का सारा कामकाज हुआ है कि नहीं?” ये महिलाएं पार्लियामेंट में जाएंगी और उनके बच्चे कौन
> सम्हालेगा? एक बच्चा रो रहा है, दूसरे की नाक बह रही है, तीसरा कहीं चला
> गया है - कौन इन बच्चों का खयाल रखेगा? यह सब उलटा हो रहा है। यह उलटी
> दुनिया है। अच्छा, पार्लियामेंट में जाकर ये महिलाएं करती क्या हैं? इस
> बारे में कुछ कहने में मुझे शरम आती है। उनके बारे में बताने का मेरा
> इरादा नहीं था, लेकिन अब बता ही देता हूं। (हंसी)।

To sum up, he basically says about gender roles:

> It is shameful thing that women are leaving their duties and going into politics.

> The decision has been taken by the Congress to bring in 222 women into
> the Lok Sabha. If women go to the Legislative Assembly, what will men
> do?

This seems in contradiction to his contributions to women's rights in India (e.g. [1](https://www.civilsdaily.com/news/babasaheb-ambedkars-womens-rights/) and [2](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/2455328X18819901)), so I am doubtful.

Is the Hindi version an accurate quote?

Comment: Could it be his viewpoints have changed over time?

Comment: @JoeW I don't think so. People's viewpoints hardly change in their old age. He died in 1956. He wrote his writings after 1947 (maybe) because he was talking about Indian politics (which was only possible after year of 1947, the independence year). By the way why people are downvoting this question? There's no rule that says you can't post other language answers. It follows all the rules too.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is being downvotes, but I doubt it's because you're asking about something written in non-English.

Comment: @F1Krazy But there's no rule against it. Plus, I translated the main sentences.

Comment: @Luffy Yes, I know. That's why I said "that's probably not the reason". One thing I will note is that you're asking two questions at once, when questions should only contain one question; "Can a government website be wrong" is a trivial "yes", so I'd suggest editing this to focus solely on whether this is a genuine quote from Ambedkar.

Comment: @F1Krazy Updated the question. Now I guess it makes more sense.

Comment: Hardly change doesn't mean that they don't change. Also is there an actual claim that is being challenged or is this just a question based on getting information from multiple sites? I am not seeing any claims that he was or wasn't a feminist.

Comment: @JoeW I thought anti-feminist is better word (less offensive) than hypocrite. I saw this post with a picture on Reddit many times. First, I thought it must be an edited picture. But I was wrong. Their claim was true (if the government Hindi version volume pdf is true). Should I change the title from anti-feminist to hypocrite?

Comment: @Luffy people's viewpoints can change as much or as little in old age as at any other time. You are simply being ageist, like old = stupid = done nothing.

Comment: There is a big difference between being pro/anti something being a hypocrite. That being said I will point back to my first comment and question of is it possible that his viewpoints changed over the course of his life.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not being ageist. I'm just expressing it's highly unlikely. His statement is contradicting his contributions towards women.

Comment: @JoeW "is it possible that his viewpoints changed over the course of his life" Thanks for the question. I researched further on this and found that he wrote this on 15 oct 1956 and dead in 6 dec 1956. It's clear now that his thoughts on this statement never changed. But yeah, I can't judge him based on this viewpoint. His viewpoints could be changed if he had lived more.

Answer (score 2):

I see that this entry is attributed to a speech Ambedkar gave on October 15, 1956 in Nagpur. I ran the text through Google Translate and, to be frank, it is totally ordinary. Nothing here calls for skepticism.

The context of this quotation is Ambedkar in retirement trying to relate to the needs of local government in Nagpur by talking about the complexities of representative democracy in general. He discusses many issues, like the need for representatives to operate on good faith and call out disinformation. The paragraph that you are quoting simply expresses his own perplexity at the question of a stay-at-home husband being asked to cook and raise children. He says "the world is upside-down these days" and is trying to solicit a laugh, which appears at the end of the paragraph. His point is that this sort of thing *does happen* in a democracy.

Ambedkar does not denounce the electoral system which allows men and women to vote for the representative of their choice, nor does he call for women to be banned from government. There is no policy proposal here. His point is only that representative democracy can confuse gender norms and that he is sympathetic to the plight of the house-husband. I am using Google Translate so I can't know if his remarks sound insensitive to a modern ear, but I think if he was denouncing female participation he would have taken on a much different tone.

Comment: Google Translate translated it in a wrong way. Instead of "It is shameful thing that women is leaving their duties", it says "There is no such shameful thing as women leaving their religion and going into politics." Did you see how it changed the context? I'm native Hindi speaker and can confirm THIS is inappropriate to say. Ambedkar was the radical person. "but I think if he was denouncing female participation he would have taken on a much different tone" But he is clearly saying that the decision (by Congress) of women in parliament is wrong. Tone doesn't matter here.

Comment: As you suggested, I changed the title.

Comment: @Luffy Thank you for changing the title. Since I can't read Hindi I cannot help you further, but I still feel like you need to look at this in light of the whole text, which doesn't imply to me any sort of anger or call for change, but lighthearted, jocular remarks delivered off the cuff.

Comment: @Luffy: I am confused. How does saying that women going into politics is not shameful mean that he is saying that women in parliament are wrong? It sounds like the complete opposite to me.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: We are going back and forth on this confusion. The Google translation should probably be added to the answer to clear it up. Google Translate says "There is no such shameful thing as women leaving their religion and going into politics." I interpret this as "There is nothing more shameful than..." Not clear how the OP is reading this.

Comment: @Oddthinking "There is nothing more shameful than..." is same as "It is shameful..." I was just writing clearly. Can you understand Hindi?

Comment: But either way: The OP doesn't think Ambedkar was misogynistic at all, and wonders if the quote is fake. [I suspect this is a naïve view of the 50s Overton Window, but that isn't an answer.] This answer seems to be "Oh, it is only mildly/casually misogynistic." but does that answer the question?

Comment: @Luffy: I can't understand Hindi, but I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: @Oddthinking Yes, I don't think Ambedkar was misogynistic since his actions (and other speeches) were totally opposite from misogynistic definition. But if his this statement is true, it's weird for me. Btw, If you can't understand Hindi, how did you interpret correctly "There is nothing more shameful than..."?

Comment: @Luffy: I think there is a false dilemma there. Ambedkar was likely progressive for the 1940s and regressive for the 2020s. Both misogynistic and anti-misogyny. I interpreted the almost-English output of Google Translate.

Comment: @Oddthinking Or we can say that human brain is complex. But if he had lived some more years, his mind/views would probably be changed as he was open minded.

Comment: @Luffy: That last sentence is unfalsifiable speculation. We are not here to attack Ambedkar, but nor are we here to write a hagiography.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I'll remember.

Answer (score 1):

> “I measure the progress of a community by the degree of progress which
> women have achieved”

[Babasaheb Ambedkar: Champion of Women´s Rights](https://gaurilankeshnews.com/babashaheb-ambedkar-champion-of-womens-rights/) and [Indian Women’s Rights Mattered to Ambedkar. Here’s What He Enabled](https://www.thequint.com/opinion/ambedkar-feminism-women-empowerment-indian-women-right-to-vote-divorce-property-rights-gender-equality) are news articles that highlight the political contributions of Dr. Ambedkar to women's right in India. ***Dr. Babasaheb Ambedkar and the question of women’s liberation in India*** – part [I](https://theleaflet.in/dr-babasaheb-ambedkar-and-the-question-of-womens-liberation-in-india-i/), [II](https://theleaflet.in/dr-babasaheb-ambedkar-and-the-question-of-womens-liberation-in-india-ii/) and [III](https://theleaflet.in/dr-babasaheb-ambedkar-and-the-question-of-womens-liberation-in-india-iii/) academically explore this subject in more detail.

*(This background is very important to not misunderstand him)*.

Ambedkar grew up in a culturally regressive indian society mixed with British Victorian values. So there are indeed some patriarchal overtones in his speech to the local public that can lead some to think that he didn't care about women's right. But, **no, he didn't say or mean that it is shameful for women to enter politics** (your Hindi-English translation is wrong, and you are also ignoring the context of the speech).

First, keep in mind that the subject of the speech is a brief comparison between parliamentary practises in England and India. As he talks about it, he speaks critically about the Indian National Congress (the party in power) that is defining India's political cultural during that period of time. The section you have quoted is his criticism that the Indian National Congress, in its eagerness to make politics accessible to women, doesn't seem to be paying attention to the character and morals of the women participating in politics.

> स्वधर्म छोड़ कर महिलाएं राजनीति करते हुए घूमें इसके जैसी शर्म की बात कोई और नहीं।

Should be interpreted as - "*There is nothing more shameful than women indulging in politics at the expense of their moral values and duties*". He then emphasises this by saying:

> महाराष्ट्र की महिलाओं द्वारा अब केवल 'कासोटा' खोलना ही बाकी रह गया है।

(Translation) "*This is akin to a Maharastrian women not being mindful of what happens when the knot tying the *saree* is pulled off.*" [He refers to the way Maharastrian women wear the *Saree* - an indian dress - that is held together with a knot. A women can be undressed with the pull of this knot, if they are not careful. He is trying to draw a parallel with women in politics who knowingly or unknowingly sometimes sacrifice their dignity, without any care.]"

Ambedkar then makes a patriarchal joke about how these kind of women spend their whole day in Parliament, bring home their work by coming home with files, asks her husband if household chores have been done etc. And jokes about what a topsy-turvy world this can be. (The crowd laughs).

He then says that he feels a bit embarrassed to speak about the character of some of these women Parliamentarian. He cites an example of a letter he received from a women politician from Maharastra who refers to Nehru very informally [without referring to Nehru with honorific or like a relative - brother, uncle etc. - as is culturally expected]. Then there were other letters too, where some woman even refers to Nehru affectionately, like a woman does to her husband. Since some of these letters were scandalous, he says, he burnt a few of these letters. *(Remember, this was an era of Victorian values)*.

Ambedkar then says he showed one of these letters to Nehru. Nehru replies that he gets a lot of irrelevant letters like this, and to ignore it. Ambedkar then tells the crowd, "*I was trying to tell him to be mindful of his public image [and of such women activists], but he was dismissive about it*".

He then concludes (this part of the speech), taking another dig at the Congress party, *"This is what I want you all to give careful thought to. What is the idea behind Congress' efforts if it allows wayward women to enter Parliament?"*

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to provide this context.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).